# Finding the Length of Javelin on the Ground

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

The question is as follows:

> A javelin lands with six feet of its length sticking out of the ground, making a 52-degree angle with the ground. The sun is directly overhead. The javelin's shadow on the ground is an example of a perpendicular projection. Find its length, to the nearest inch.

I do not have any idea as to how I should start approaching this problem. It's mainly because I cannot visualise this properly given the details given in the problem. I would greatly appreciate it if someone can explain this problem to me along with visuals.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it a basic trigonometric problem?

Comment: I would assume so. I need help with drawing the visual. I am pretty sure that once I am able to see this visually, then I will be able to figure out the answer through trig.

Comment: This is an unfortunately-worded problem. It’s impossible to find the javelin’s length because you’re not told what fraction of it is sticking out of the ground. You can, however, determine the length of its visible part. You say that you can’t visualize the problem. Have you dried drawing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sun is directly overhead, the javelin casts a shadow directly underneath the part of the javelin that sticks out of the ground.

[image: projection_of_shadow_of_javelin_on_the_ground]

What you need to do is find $s$, the length of the shadow that the javelin projects on the ground.  Which trigonometric ratio relates the length of the shadow to the length of the javelin?

Comment: $s$ would be found by multiplying 6 with $cos52$. I just realized that they wanted for me to find the length of the shadow, not the length of the javelin. Thank you!